# Python threading blocked by keyboard library?

Tags: python, multithreading, keyboard

while building a script that can be toggled to spam. I encountered the following problem.
first is the normal functioning version of the script:

```
import keyboard
import threading

def spam_this():
    status = 0
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("F9") and status == 0:
            status = 1
            event.wait(1)
        if keyboard.is_pressed("F9") and status == 1:
            status = 0
            event.wait(1)
        while status == 1:
            if keyboard.is_pressed("F9") and status == 1:
                status = 0
                event.wait(1)
            print("test")

event = threading.Event()
threading.Thread(target=spam_this).start()
```

the script above works perfectly. however, when I change the line `print("test")` to `keyboard.write("test")`. the script breaks.

```
import keyboard
import threading

def spam_this():
    status = 0
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("F9") and status == 0:
            status = 1
            event.wait(1)
        if keyboard.is_pressed("F9") and status == 1:
            status = 0
            event.wait(1)
        while status == 1:
            if keyboard.is_pressed("F9") and status == 1:
                status = 0
                event.wait(1)
            keyboard.write("test")

event = threading.Event()
threading.Thread(target=spam_this).start()
```

this version of the script with the `keyboard.write()` function can be initiated with the implimented toggle key "F9", but when I try to toggle off the switch by pressing "F9" again, it does not stop like the `print("test")` version of itself.

note: I am not sure how to word this problem in the title. I use the term "blocked" because the effect is similar to what blocking method like `time.sleep()` would do when trying to create a `while True:` loop with a toggle.

Comment: if you run code in `while status == 1` then you don't have to check `and status == 1`

Comment: if you would use `True/False` instead of `0/1` then you could use `status = not status` and use only one `if` (without `and status == ...`)` before `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import threading
import keyboard

# global variable
status = False

def spam_this():
    print('start: spam_this')
    while True:
        if status is True:
            print("test")
            keyboard.write("test")
            event.wait(0.1)
        
            
def test(event=None):
    global status
    status = not status
    print('change:', status)

event = threading.Event()
keyboard.add_hotkey("F9", test)
#alternatively:
#keyboard.on_key_press("F9", test)
threading.Thread(target=spam_this).start()
```

there are a few modifications that has been made to @furas's answers.

1. for the `test` function, a parameter `event=None` was added, otherwise the `keyboard.on_press_key` will pass the `F9` key-pressed-event to the test function, which results in a `typeError`.
2. in the `test` function, the `event.wait()` was removed due to an error, and upon testing, the `keyboard.on_press_key` and `keyboard.add_hotkey` function does have inbuilt delays, so as long as the `F9` key was not HELD down, the inbuilt delays are more than enough.
3. regardless of whether using `on_key_press` or `add_hotkey`, the thread should be initialized AFTER the desired "hotkey method" is called. otherwise the thread will block the main loop of the python script.(this part I cannot explain why, it was just trial and error leading to this conclusion.)
4. the `keyboard.wait()` was removed, because this function was not used.

NUMBER 1 and 3 ARE THE MOST IMPORTANT CHANGES
(for the people who doesn't want to read through the minor bits)

Answer (score 0):

`keyboard` may run own code also in `thread` and there can be conflict between two threads. Python uses `GIL` to run only one thread at a time - so when your thread is running then it may block thread which should write text on screen. Code works better if I use `even.wait(0.1)` after `write()` so Python can switch threads and send text on screen. If you use longer value then it also work but if you press key very fast then it may stil run `write` or `wait` and it can't check `is_pressed("F9")` and not stop it - you should see it if you use `event.wait(1)` after `write`

There is also  other problem - it may write last text after pressing key and  it should use `break` to exit `while` and skip `write`

```
import threading
import keyboard

def spam_this():
    status = 0
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("F9") and status == 0:
            status = 1
            event.wait(1)
        if keyboard.is_pressed("F9") and status == 1:
            status = 0
            event.wait(1)
        while status == 1:
            if keyboard.is_pressed("F9") and status == 1:
                print('stop')
                status = 0
                event.wait(1)
                break
            keyboard.write("test")
            event.wait(0.1)

event = threading.Event()
threading.Thread(target=spam_this).start()
```

But I would reduce it to

```
import threading
import keyboard

def spam_this():
    print('start spam_this')
    status = False
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("F9"):
            status = not status
            print('status:', status)
            event.wait(0.1)
        if status is True:
            keyboard.write("test")
            event.wait(0.1)

event = threading.Event()
threading.Thread(target=spam_this).start()
```

But it has another problem - if you keep pressed key longer time then it will switch `status` many times. I added `print('status:', status)` to show it.

I was thinking to use `keyboard.add_hotkey` like this

```
import threading
import keyboard

# global variable
status = False

def spam_this():
    print('start: spam_this')
    while True:
        if status is True:
            keyboard.write("test")
            event.wait(0.1)

def test():
    global status
    
    status = not status
    print('change:', status)
    event.wait(0.5)
    
event = threading.Event()
threading.Thread(target=spam_this).start()
    
keyboard.add_hotkey("F9", test)
keyboard.wait()
```

but when you keep pressed key then system may start sending the same key again.

I didn't test `keyboard.on_press_key()` - maybe it would resolve it.

Doc: [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard)

Comment: I did add ```event.wait(1)``` after the ```status``` toggle part because I noticed rapid altering between ```0``` and ```1``` state when the key is press, but I did not think of adding a ```wait``` after the ```keyboard.write()```. after further testing with the ```event.wait()```. sometimes the toggle can be achieved when set to 0.2 during testing, but it is still very unreliable. as for the ```keyboard.add_hotkey``` method, ```threading``` blocks the main functions after that. I will post an updated version of it when its working.

Comment: after testing, the ```on_key_press``` method works like a charm too.